# Signing a firefox add-on with Mozilla api and download signed xpi

Tags: firefox-addon, amo

I'm using the Mozilla API to upload an add-on and signing it (following [this 
guide](http://olympia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/api/signing.html)).

After uploading the add-on, I receive the first answer from the api as a json, that looks like [that](https://gist.github.com/arieljannai/20500b3f0ad86bb8f880#file-upload-amo-result-json). From that response, I'm taking the url field and accessing it ([result](https://gist.github.com/arieljannai/20500b3f0ad86bb8f880#file-status-amo-result-json)), that way I can see the status of my add-on signing.

The thing that I don't get, is why although the add-on is marked as signed for my understanding (active, passed_review, processed, reviewd, valid are all set to true), the xpi file (`result.files[0].download_url`) is marked as `signed=false`.

Does anyone knows why is that? How can I get my xpi signed and download it?
Maybe it has to do with the warnings I have on the add-on? (although they're marked as fine).

[The curl commands I'm executing](https://gist.github.com/arieljannai/20500b3f0ad86bb8f880#file-curl-commands-sh).

Thanks,
Ariel.

*P.S - Can't use [jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm) cause It's not the add-ons format we currently have.*

Comment: is your addon listed on AMO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that behavior resulted from a bad `install.rdf` configuration. I had a wrong targetApplication id (firefox, thunderbird, etc..), and when I fixed that and tried again it worked, and I got `signed=true`.

I also [opened an issue](https://github.com/mozilla/olympia/issues/1522) about it in the [github project](https://github.com/mozilla/olympia) of https://addons.mozilla.org

P.S - From [jpm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpm) v1.0.5 it is possible to sign a non-SDK (Xul, WebExtensions) add-on with the [jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm) tool ([github](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm)):
`jpm sign --api-key <key> --api-secret <secret> --xpi <filePath.xpi>` (works great!)

Answer (score 1):

I also used the API to sign and download non-sdk addon - https://github.com/Noitidart/Chrome-Store-Foxified/blob/ee3ad5486fa1539b88670f30e66fe277ec6d8afd/bootstrap.js#L208-L215

I think the `signed` means physically passed review and got signed that way. Not `auto-signed`.

Don't worry your addon is signed.

Comment: according to the [signing documentation](http://olympia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/api/signing.html) it should be true. And actually it's not really signed, I've figured out the problem - I had problems in my install.rdf